# Thinking Sphinx: rake ts:start, ts:stop and ts:rebuild are all giving errors, searchd is still running?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

After I run `rake ts:index` and try to start the sphinx server I get these errors for all of my commands:

```
$ rake ts:start
rake aborted!
searchd is already running.

$ rake ts:stop
rake aborted!
execution expired

$ rake ts:rebuild
rake aborted!
execution expired
```

I tried what was in this these threads already:

[Thinking Sphinx Rake aborted, searchd is running while rebuilding or start/stop ts. Index works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040995/thinking-sphinx-rake-aborted-searchd-is-running-while-rebuilding-or-start-stop)

[Any ideas why Thinking Sphinx Rake tasks are not running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809852/any-ideas-why-thinking-sphinx-rake-tasks-are-not-running)

But those commands aren't recognized on my system e.g. `searchd --stop` and I am not to sure how I would use those commands on my system in the first place.

How do I fix this?

Comment: And a quick way to kill a process is to use powershell: `kill (ps "notepad").id`

Comment: @Zabba The error is "execution expired".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like something was wrong with the gem when I installed it the first time. I switch to `gem 'thinking-sphinx', '2.0.9'` and back to `gem 'thinking-sphinx', '2.0.10'` using `bundle install`. I also reinstalled Sphinx just encase.